# iOS: Playing a video on application launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am new to Xcode so I've been trying to follow along to tutorials but haven't come across any that explain what I'm trying to achieve. I just want to play a video automatically when you open an application. I have it somewhat working in that the audio plays, but I cannot see any video. Am I missing something? I am getting this Warning in my output window:

> Warning: Attempt to present MPMoviePlayerViewController: 0x831d7a0 on ViewController: 0x9d10540 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

In my `ViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

`ViewController.m`:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Placeholder" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playercontroller = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playercontroller];
    playercontroller.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
    [playercontroller.moviePlayer play];
    playercontroller = nil;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Move all your code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: I tried, but it just gives me a blank screen with no audio either.

Comment: At least you do not get any errors. So now check if that viewDidAppear code is actually invoked (add an `NSLog` or a breakpoint).

Comment: Tried adding NSLog(@"The code runs through here"); but it doesn't seem it's getting to it.

Comment: Thought so. How are you presenting that ViewController? Are you simply assigning it to be the app windows' `rootViewController`?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm brand new to this. The above 2 files are the only ones I've edited. I haven't done anything in the Interface Builder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28768/discussion-between-till-and-downtomike)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
[playercontroller.moviePlayer play];
```

do

```
[playercontroller play];
```

**Side note:**
Also check up on your naming convention. In Objective-C variable names "should" have capital letter on each new word in the variable. E.g. instead of `playercontroller` use `playerController`.

Comment: I tried but no luck. It's telling me 'MPMoviePlayerViewController' may not respond to 'play'. I forgot to mention the warning I was receiving in my original post so I edited it to include it.

Comment: @Filip it will not as he is using `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

I know your status.

it's warning from Xcode.

So, you just change the code.

like this,

```
[playercontroller performSelector:@selector(player)];
```